# Patch request to express-openid-connect 405

Tags: node.js, express, express-openid-connect

I am using following environment:
node 18.0.0, npm 8.6.0, express-openid-connect 2.16.0.
and use

```
    const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
app.use(
  auth({
    issuerBaseURL: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN',
    baseURL: 'https://YOUR_APPLICATION_ROOT_URL',
    clientID: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    secret: 'LONG_RANDOM_STRING',
    idpLogout: true,
  })
);
```

It works well with GET and POTS but for PATCH, DELETE, PUT I get 405 as follows.[image]

Can you help me to support PATCH too?